# Higher vector spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

As far as I know there are different ways to categorify the notion of vector space/module. These appear (for example) when trying to find extended TQFTs. There are at least two ways (presented at [$2$-vector-space at nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-vector+space) and more generally in the article on $(\infty,n)$-modules):

- The 2-category $\mathsf{Vect}_2$ whose objects are $k$-linear categories, $1$-morphisms are functors and $2$-morphims are natural transformations;
- The 2-category $1\text{-}\mathsf{Alg}$ whose objects are associative $k$-algebras, morphisms are bimodules and $2$-morphisms are bimodules morphisms.

The two are linked by some kind of Tannaka duality: there's a functor $1\text{-}\mathsf{Alg} \to \mathsf{Vect}_2$ (described [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2Cn%29-module)) that maps an algebra $A$ to its category of modules $\mathsf{RMod}_A$, an $(A,B)$ bimodule $N$ to the functor $- \otimes_A N$, and a bimodule morphism to the associated natural transformation.

I think this is fully faithful but not essentially surjective. Am I right? How to describe the essential image of this functor? A category in the image has to at least be monoidal and rigid, for example. Is the image possibly the fully dualizable objects?

Comment: Not all categories in the image are monoidal, think of a noncommutative $A$.

Comment: One needs commutative or an $(A,B^{op})$-bimodule. Otherwise the tensor functor will go to left modules instead of right modules. The image should be described by using a $k$-linear version of Morita's theorem: There should exist a compact progenitor. What do you mean by fully faithful for a $2$-functor?

Comment: @Fernando You're right, I'm not sure what I was thinking. Conditions include being abelian, though.

Comment: @Julian Are you sure? If $M$ is a right $A$-mod and $N$ is an $(A,B)$-bimodule then $M \otimes_A N$ is a right $B$-mod no? For fully faithful I meant that $\mathrm{Map}(A,B) \to \mathrm{Map}(F(A), F(B))$ should have been an equivalence of categories, but I've been told since then it's not true (indeed all functors of the form $- \otimes_A N$ preserve colimits, for example).

Comment: Yes, sure. I was mixing up the tensor products, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I already noted in the comments: A $k$-linear category is equivalent to a module category iff it is abelian, cocomplete, and there exists a compact projective generator. This is a version of Morita's theorem, which can be found e.g. in [this article by Bernhard Keller](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/publ/cam.pdf). 
For the question about which functors are equivalent to tensor functors the answer is given by Eilenberg-Watts theorem stating that these are exactly the functors which are right exact and preserve small coproducts (see e.g. Athens following article in nlab: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Watts+theorem )

Comment: Thanks. That first statement is true for abelian categories, right? (ie. if $C$ is abelian, then $C$ is a category of representations iff...).

Comment: @Najib Idrissi Yes, I changed accordingly.

Comment: The category of finite dimensional $k$ vector spaces is Abelian and has a compact projective generator. How do you distinguish this from, say, the category of all vector spaces?

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries Thanks for pointing out this mistake. Of course the category should be cocomplete, otherwise there is the question what compact should mean if you don't have coproducts. I don't know of a theorem describing what properties describe finite dimensional vector spaces (or more general finitely generated, finitely presented, or coherent modules over a ring).

Comment: Well, there is a trivial observation: an idempotent-complete category $\mathcal{C}$ is (equivalent to) the category of finitely presented $R$-modules if and only if $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ is (equivalent to) the category of $R$-modules.

Comment: There is the following characterization which might be useful (k is a field): an abelian k-linear category is equivalent to the category of finite dimensional representations of a finite dimensional algebra iff (1) All homs are finite dimensional (2) Every object has finite length (3) there are enough projectives (e.g. if there is a projective generator) and (4) up to isomorphism there are finitely many simple objects. This is well-known in the right communities, and a proof can be found here arXiv:1406.4204.